# 14.04 LTS won't boot after kernel update to 3.13.0.117

Tags: boot

Updated kernel from 3.13.0-116-generic to 3.13.0.117-generic as prompted by the Update Manager. Now the computer fails to boot and loops back to a hardware re-start. If I select the Ubuntu boot options and use the previous kernel (.116) the computer boots normally.